# Problems with NSTimer: Wrong logic?

Tags: objective-c

Here, I've got something like:

```
void start() { for (id i in something) { [i start]; } }
void finish() { for (id i in something) { [i finish]; } }

static NSTimer *timer = nil;

@implementation aClass
- (void)start {
    if (!timer) timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(change) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)change { /* ... */ }
- (void)finish { [timer invalidate]; }
@end
```

Note that I cannot use ivars, and as you can assume there are a lot of `aClass` instances having `-start` called.

I think I am facing an issue with my own logic here, as only one single instance (the first to have `-start` called) gets `-change` called at the same time. It's not an issue with the other instances, since if I remove the first object from the `something` array, then the second will be alright, and the others face issues.

Am I just making some obvious mistake? (I think I am; trying to use the same global for every instance...).  And how can I fix such issue?

Answer (score 3):

You're using a static NSTimer variable, which means that there is only one `timer` pointer for all of your class' instances. The first instance that gets `-start` called will then set the target of the timer to itself and the other ones don't do anything, because `timer` isn't `nil` any longer.

You'll have to use an ivar for the `timer` pointer, I don't understand why this should be an issue...

Comment: Again, I **can't** use ivars. (if I could, this answer would have solved my issues though.)

Comment: And why not? You can use associated objects then.

Comment: I also thought of that, and I've had a couple of issues on it. I'll give it another shot though, thanks!

Comment: Can you use an array of `NSTimer`s instead of only one? You may associate `timerArray[i]` with `something[i]`, thus each class will have its own timer...

Comment: You'd have to use a static NSMutableDictionary then and use the pointer as the key and remove the object from the dictionary in dealloc. But associated objects should work fine. Make sure to use a retained association.